# Jersey: Decoding String @PathParam which contains space in it

Tags: java, jersey

```
public Response getCustomerByName(
@PathParam("customerName") String customerName)
```

**Problem** : 
I am passing customerName as : **stack overflow** (URL is encoded as : **stack%20overflow**). I want to receive as decoded string (stack overflow, without %20) in my java code.

**What I tried** : 
This works perfectly fine, but I felt it is not more generic way of doing it.

```
URLDecoder.decode(customerName, "UTF-8");
```

**Require more generic solution :**
I want to do the similar changes in rest of the APIs as well, so using URLDecoder in each API is burden . Is there any common practice which I can follow to impose this decoding at application level? (@PathParam is already decoded when I receive the request)

Comment: If you are using Tomcat, try to set URIEncoding = "UTF-8" in server.xml

Comment: Hi Marco, Thank you. Let me try this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shall be auto "Decoded" and you don't need explicit decoding using `URLDecoder.decode(customerName, "UTF-8");`

As mentioned in javadoc of [PathParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) javadoc:

> The value is URL decoded unless this is disabled using the Encoded annotation.

I just verified below and it works as per javadoc (in weblogic server)

```
@GET
@Produces(value = { "text/plain"})
@Path("{customerName}")
public Response getCustomerByName(@PathParam("customerName") String customerName) {
    System.out.println(customerName);
    return Response.ok().entity(customerName).type("text/plain").build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That makes me think somewhere in application (filters/listener) decoding logic is overwritten.